# file_upload doesnt work on some images. Hangs then 504

Tags: php

Ive been trying to figure out whats going on with this for over 2 weeks and still no closer.

im pulling my hair right now.

it works for 1 image but it doesnt for another? and it doesnt take long at all.

I put in a basic script and it still times out on a specific image...

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

and the 2 images are....

https://smokeology.ca/1.png
https://smokeology.ca/2.jpeg

first image works but times out on second.

im throwing up phpinfo too...

https://smokeology.ca/phpinfo.php

and the test script...

https://smokoelogy.ca/test.html

logs say nothing.

Comment: Are you miss spelling every other domain name intentionally?

Comment: I dont get what you mean.

Comment: https://smokeology.ca/2.png → File not found (404)

Comment: fixed my mistake

Comment: I have checked your codes, no problem at all (actually I can upload your 2nd file based on your codes in my server).

Please double check that the "uploads" folder exists and is writable.

Comment: it exists and permissions are set to www-data i checked.

Comment: also important to note i can upload the first image just fine its the second image which is a jpeg that hangs for some reason. so it cant be folders or permissiosn otherwise it would have failed on the first image.